# In FusionCharts why does my yAxis start at -100

Tags: fusioncharts

I have a multi-series area chart with values from 1 to 400.
The Y-Axis appears to start at -100.  I have no data values below 0.

if I set yaxisminvalue it has no impact.
I've tried setting min and max values, they seem to have no relevance.

If I set my min to a large amount (say 10,000) , then it seems to work.

yaxismin
yaxismax
min